# Intercalar 2 Arrays

Tags: javascript

Hola necesito intercalar 2 arrays en js, un nombre, un apellido, un nombre un apellido, probe todo pero no lo consigo, si alguien tiene una idea... se lo agradeceria, solo logre insertar un apellido entre 2 nombres con splace pero busco que se intercalen completamente:

```
var nombre=["Laura","Matías","Danlois","Jose","Romina","Facundo","Leonardo","Andres","Matias","Santiago","Jhon","Lucas","Greta","Franco","Natalia","Paula","Jose","Luciana","Nicolas","Miguel","Javier","Matt","Hernan", "Federico","Matias","Christian","Ezequiel","Jimmy","Johanna","Peter","Milagros","Evelin","Audelio","Valeria","Johanna","Constanza","Gonzalo","Tiago"];
var apellido=["Molares","Matsumoto","Tovar","Alzogaray","Nievas","Torres","Albornoz","Rojas","Dulce","Gimenez","Fagundez","Resa","Liverotti","Lazatti","Miremont","Farias","Barrera","Vargas","Seguro","Nefle","Mayan","Acevedo","Balsas","Ventura","Edorna","Pochi","Robles","Velasquez","Poblette","Diaz","Suarez","Aragon","Gauto","Gonzalez","Santos","Jaramillo","Fernandez","Viezzoli"];
nombre.splace(1,0, apellido);

console.log(nombre.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé cuál es la salida que desearías pero con [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) podrías obtener un nuevo `array` con todos los nombre-apellidos deseados. Con él recorres el `array` de nombres y devuelves el valor de cada iteración (`v`) con el valor `i` del `array` de apellidos. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var nombre=["Laura","Matías","Danlois","Jose","Romina","Facundo","Leonardo","Andres","Matias","Santiago","Jhon","Lucas","Greta","Franco","Natalia","Paula","Jose","Luciana","Nicolas","Miguel","Javier","Matt","Hernan", "Federico","Matias","Christian","Ezequiel","Jimmy","Johanna","Peter","Milagros","Evelin","Audelio","Valeria","Johanna","Constanza","Gonzalo","Tiago"];
var apellido=["Molares","Matsumoto","Tovar","Alzogaray","Nievas","Torres","Albornoz","Rojas","Dulce","Gimenez","Fagundez","Resa","Liverotti","Lazatti","Miremont","Farias","Barrera","Vargas","Seguro","Nefle","Mayan","Acevedo","Balsas","Ventura","Edorna","Pochi","Robles","Velasquez","Poblette","Diaz","Suarez","Aragon","Gauto","Gonzalez","Santos","Jaramillo","Fernandez","Viezzoli"];

var nombreApellido = nombre.map(function(v, i) {
  return `${v} ${apellido[i]}`;
});

console.log(nombreApellido);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Exactamente lo que queria